# React JS - I'm having difficult to get JSON informations from API on a Select box in my project

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I'm new to React and JSON stuff, so I'm having some trouble to get JSON information and put it on an Option tag inside the Select on my project. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchData();
      }

      fetchData() {
        fetch("https://grupoprever-api.qap/listas/estados", { mode: "cors" })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(parsedJSON => {
            parsedJSON.map(estado => ({
              v: `${estado.key}`,
              d: `${estado.value}`
            }));
          })

          .then(estados =>
            this.setState({
              estados
            })
          )

          .catch(error => console.log("Erro no Fetch:", error));
      }
```

And I'm trying to put this information in here:

```
    <div className="meioCampo">
              <span>Estado:</span>
              <select
                id="estadosDropdown"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ escolhidoEstado: e.target.value })}
              >
                {this.state.estados.map(estado => {
                  return (
                    <option key={estado.v} value={estado.v}>
                      {estado.d}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
```

All of this are inside a Component.

Oh, my JSON data is like this:

```
{

    "AC":"Acre",
    "AL":"Alagoas",
    "AM":"Amaz\u00f4nia"

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What format does the data response from the api call have?

Comment: @MikeAbeln hey man ! im having this: TypeError: "parsedJSON.map is not a function" . My JSON data is like this: {"AC":"Acre","AL":"Alagoas","AM":"Amaz\u00f4nia"}

Comment: Ah! You're trying to iterate over an object – which is not iterable. `.map` functions run on `Array` data types, and run some code for each item, in sequential order. Your JSON object is an `Object` data type – it doesn't have a sequential order and can't be mapped over.

Comment: @MikeAbeln woww ! D: thats true. Is there a way i can do it like this json or i should organize this information inside a array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning any data from a `map` function.

change

```
.then(parsedJSON => {
    parsedJSON.map(estado => ({
      v: `${estado.key}`,
      d: `${estado.value}`
    }));
 })
```

to

```
.then(parsedJSON => {
    return parsedJSON.map(estado => ({
      v: `${estado.key}`,
      d: `${estado.value}`
    }));
  })
```

EDIT:

Also please don't call your api from `componentWillMount` method. While your code might be working, this lifecycle method is already marked as UNSAFE and should be avoided. Call your fetch request from `componentDidMount` instead. Initialize default state of your Component like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ... // your other code in constructor

  this.state = {
     estados: null,
     // add other state variables here...
  }
}
```

and add a check for 'null' state to your `render()` method like so:

```
<div className="meioCampo">
  <span>Estado:</span>
  <select
    id="estadosDropdown"
    onChange={e => this.setState({ escolhidoEstado: e.target.value })}         >
      {this.state.estados && this.state.estados.map(estado => {
        return (
          <option key={estado.v} value={estado.v}>
            {estado.d}
          </option>
        );
      })}
 </select>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

as your response body is an object (not list), then you can try to following code:

```
fetchData() {
  fetch("https://grupoprever-api.qap/listas/estados", { mode: "cors" })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(estados =>
       this.setState({
          estados
      })
    );
```

then generate your options list with `Object.keys()` method:

```
render() {
   ....
  const {estados} = this.state;

  return(
    <div className="meioCampo">
      <span>Estado:</span>
      <select
        id="estadosDropdown"
        onChange={e => this.setState({ escolhidoEstado: e.target.value })}         >
          {estados && Object.keys(estados).map(key => {
            return (
              <option key={key} value={key}>
                {estados[key]}
              </option>
            );
          })}
     </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer and your tips. But it didnt work here :( . I keep getting the error: TypeError: "parsedJSON.map is not a function". Any other ideia whats wrong with my code ? :/

Comment: I think my JSON data is broken :/ ,ive add it to the question body, if you could take a look, thanks dude.

Comment: I've edited my answer for you.. hope it will help.. maybe you will need to parse json() to object with JSON.parse(estados) I'm not sure about that one...

Comment: IT WORK ! Thank you so much ! it really helps me. Now im going to study more, and dominate this JSON things haha. Thanks !